# spotify web api connection

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spotipy

```
import spotipy
import requests
import sys
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
# Setup the credentials
client_credentials_manager = 
SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret)

# Make the connection
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager,auth=access_token)
sp.current_user()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _internal_call(self, 
method, url, payload, params)
118         try:
--> 119             r.raise_for_status()
120         except:

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in raise_for_status(self)
934         if http_error_msg:
 --> 935             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
936 

HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: 
 https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 SpotifyException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-12-a36bf58a0704> in <module>()
----> 1 sp.current_user()

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in current_user(self)
572             An alias for the 'me' method.
573         '''
--> 574         return self.me()
575 
576     def current_user_saved_albums(self, limit=20, offset=0):

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in me(self)
566             An alias for the 'current_user' method.
567         '''
--> 568         return self._get('me/')
569 
570     def current_user(self):

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _get(self, url, args, 
payload, **kwargs)
144         while retries > 0:
145             try:
 --> 146                 return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, 
 kwargs)
147             except SpotifyException as e:
148                 retries -= 1

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _internal_call(self, 
method, url, payload, params)
122                 raise SpotifyException(r.status_code,
123                     -1, '%s:\n %s' % (r.url, r.json()['error'] 
['message']),
--> 124                     headers=r.headers)
125             else:
126                 raise SpotifyException(r.status_code,

SpotifyException: http status: 401, code:-1 - 
https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/:
 Unauthorized.
```

Is this the right way to connect to spotify api? i been trying to get details through spotify API that requires auth token. i do have all 3 in my code(just not posted here). i m still getting this bad request error.

Comment: where do you get `access_token`? it doesn't look like it's defined anywhere here

Comment: token = util.oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="a3866f84e8a8e3", client_secret="Replace")

cache_token = token.get_access_token()
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(cache_token)

print(cache_token)

Comment: this is how i got the token from.... is it the right one to use?

Comment: Can you update your question with that info?

Answer (score 0):

there is no error in code. was using the wrong access_token.